# Max size maior de 2MB no upload de ficheiros DOCman

Tags: php, servidor, joomla, cpanel

Quando tento enviar um ficheiro pelo DOCman do Joomla ele não me deixa enviar ficheiros maiores de 2MB. Entretando já estive a ver todas as configurações do cpanel e tem todas um bom limite. Aqui fica um print das configurações que meti no cpanel, mas mesmo assim não dá:

[image: SS]

Imagem do erro no joomla: 
[image: SS]

Comment: Não seria alguma configuração no Joomla ?

Comment: Verifique também a configuração do `post_max_size`

Comment: @gmsantos o post_max_size tambem está a 200M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver do seguinte modo. Criei um ficheiro php.ini dentro da pasta e meti lá a seguinte linha:

```
upload_max_filesize = 128M
```

Answer (score 1):

Tente alterar os limites em tempo de execução. Acrescente está linhas no inicio do seu script

```
ini_set("memory_limit", "64M");
ini_set("upload_max_filesize", "16M");
```

Comment: pode especificar melhor onde posso meter essas linhas? é que com o joomla não é fácil meter essas linhas no script

Comment: @pc_oc, vai usar na própria página PHP. Veja a [**DOC sobre ini_set**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ini-set.php)